# the jenkins executor auto reset for a while deploy by kubernetes way

Tags: jenkins

When I using jenkins to build project , the build always give tips:

```
Started by user admin
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/xiaoqiang-blog-source.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
Waiting for next available executor on ‘master’
```

so I  have to tweak the executor number, but after a while, the executor auto turn to 0, and I have to tweak it again, why would this happen? My jenkins is deploy in kubernetes v1.18 cluster.

[image]

does anyone encount the same problem. Why the executor turn to 0 automatically?